# How to bind in WPF a combo box to an enum from an other project?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, enums

Here is my problem.
I have a WPF application that contains a combo box.
I want to bind this combo box to an enum from an other project.

In my application (AdapterApp), I tried this :

```
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Adapter"

    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataFromEnum" MethodName="GetValues" 
                                    ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="local:MyEnum"/>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataFromEnum}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,113,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150"/>
```

In my other project :

```
namespace Adapter
{
 public enum MyEnum
 {
    Lent = 0,
    Rapide
  };
 }
```

I have this error :

> The name "MyEnum" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Adapter".

What did I wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a reference to your other project, and then define `otherProjectNamespace` namespace as `xmlns:otherProjectNamespace="clr-namespace:Adapter;assembly=MyOtherProject"`.

If you don't specify the assembly, compiler tries to find the `Adapter` namespace in the current assembly (i.e. assembly of your application).